# (Vue.js) On the github page, the inside of '#app' is empty

Tags: vue.js, github, github-pages

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/views/Home.vue'
import Load from '@/views/Load.vue'
import Login from '@/views/Login.vue'
import Main from '@/views/Main.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/load',
    name: 'loading',
    component: Load
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/main',
    name: 'main',
    component: Main
  }]
})
```

I connected the router correctly.

But https://sh031224.github.io/portfolio/ the inside of '#app' is empty.

How can I do?

My github is https://github.com/Sh031224/portfolio
And github page is https://sh031224.github.io/portfolio/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `base` in your router configuration to `"/portfolio/"`

See the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base)